# UISwitch value getting recycled in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a UITableView with custom cell that I have built. In each custom cell, I have added a UISwitch. My tableview is only 100px tall. When I have 6 or more cells, it seems to start recycling the UISwitches on the cells, so if I change the value of the switch in cell 0, the switch at cell 5 will also change its value to match that of cell 0. Is there a way to control the memory to prevent this from happening?

Thanks.

Comment: can you show some code of how you add the uiswitches to your custom cell?

Comment: I created the custom cell in IB

Comment: How do you differentiate the switches? By tag? Can you show that code?

Comment: I just solved it. I used a boolean array to keep track of the switch values, and kept track of the different switches using tags. As the table view loads, I sent the switch values based on the boolean value in the array.

Comment: We need to see your cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Most likely you are not setting the switch property for a dequeued cell.

Comment: @Heather yea always use tags to differentiate 2 different uiswitches if you have multiple switches in one view. Upvote our comments if you found them helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used tags to keep track of which switches were which in the table view by using

```
cell.cellSwitch.tag = indexPath.row;
```

I was then able to go back and reference the correct switch in my code.